# How can I get the Zoom button to be visible while I'm on the Home tab?

Tags: autocad, cad

I'm using AutoCAD 2015.  While I'm drawing, I spend most of my time on the Home ribbon tab.  I like the Zoom ribbon button, but it is on the View tab.  Is there any way to move the Zoom button to the Home tab, so I don't have to switch ribbon tabs to hit it?  Alternatively, is there any way to add the Zoom button (or at least just a Zoom Extents or a Zoom All button) to the bottom toolbar, or somewhere where it will be visible all the time?

I am aware that I can do a Zoom Extents just by typing "Z-Enter-E-Enter", but I like my toolbar button.  :)

Comment: "but I like my toolbar button" - Buttons always feel wrong to me in AutoCAD, but I learned before buttons were very common.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD has a very nice ability to customize the user interface. Essentially you build a custom tab with the commands that you would like in your own configuration.

Per comments: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-27573791-DCEE-4751-A18A-7E54E773BEF6-htm.html

Comment: Saying "this feature exists" is far less helpful than describing how to access and use it.